# How long does a work loop in React internal last?

Tags: reactjs, event-loop, react-fiber

Recent I was watching [a video talking about react fiber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs), what confused me was that where **every work loop's time** came from. Is it constant or mutable depending on any variables?

At first, I thought it's 1000/60 ~= 16.6 ms until I saw this picture [image]

Comment: 16.66ms is 60 frames per second. Most of other numbers are likely to be made up for demonstration purposes. Please specify the numbers and timestamp in the video you are wondering about.

Comment: @UjinT34  Thanks for your suggestion, just updated the question.